# Change $sum result type in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Here is my query :

```
db.log.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "meta.userId": {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: null
        },
        "timestamp": {
            $gte: ISODate("2016-01-01"),
            $lte: ISODate("2016-01-07")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$meta.userId",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

When using `{ $sum: 1 }` in aggregation pipeline, the shell returns a *double*. I'd like it to return directly an *integer* as it's just a count of documents.

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "foo",
        "count" : 46.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "foo1",
        "count" : 146.0000000000000000
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Any idea of how I could change the type of sum ?

My version of MongoDB is 3.0.7. I use Robomongo 0.8.5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explictely specify the value `1` is an integer using `NumberInt`, see this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-854) ticket. This is normally not needed when running similar queries in the MongoDB shell, so this might be a feature of Robomongo.

```
db.log.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "meta.userId": {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: null
        },
        "timestamp": {
            $gte: ISODate("2016-01-01"),
            $lte: ISODate("2016-01-07")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$meta.userId",
        count: {
            $sum: NumberInt(1)
        }
    }
}])
```